# How to transfer every artifact from Nexus to AWS CodeArtifact?

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, nexus, aws-codeartifact, nexus3-api

I should migrate every artifact from Nexus to another solution, preferably AWS CodeArtifact because of company regulations.

We have hosted, proxy and group type repos as well, mostly maven and nuget.

The best idea I’ve had so far was to use the Nexus REST API and create some kind of a script to automatically download all artifacts, and upload them back to AWS CA, but I’m not sure if that’s the best solution. It’s also important to keep the folder structure the same as it is on the Nexus web UI.

I’m pretty new to Nexus and artifact repos in general, so any tip would be appreciated.

Comment: “Keep the folder structure the same” - what does this mean?

Comment: I guess you have to use script to do this. There is automation for this.